# k fold cross validation with regularisation R code - unsure whether it is correct

Tags: r, machine-learning, cross-validation, regularization

I'm working through a book called A First Course In Machine Learning. The first chapter introduces K-fold Cross Validation as well as other validation methods, and then has a few paragraphs on regularisation. The explanations are very brief, and I am coming to these concepts for the first time.

There are exercises but no solutions, so I am unsure whether I am completing them correctly. The book mainly focusses on the use of Matlab, but there is some sample code available for Python and R on [GitHub](https://github.com/sdrogers/fcmlcode/tree/master/R).

The final exercise of chapter 1 presents Olympic Men's data for the 100m and asks to produce a K-fold cross validation and select a regularisation parameter for a 1st order model, and a fourth order model; then compare the two regularisation parameters that give the best predictive performance.

To do this I wrote an R Function that combined the K-fold cross validation to find model parameters, and a secant function to converge on a minimum value of lambda (for the regularisation parameter). See the function provided.

```
KFCV_REG_lsq <- function(x, y, n, K){
  
  # x = Independent data
  # y = Dependent data
  # n = Order of function
  # K = Number of datapoints per fold
  
  folds <- floor(length(x)/K) # This will create a number of folds containing 10 datapoints.
  
  sizes <- rep(K, folds) # Number of segments of equal length
  
  csizes = c(0,cumsum(sizes)) # Need use this to create the segments of training data
  
  if(length(x) - max(csizes) >= 1){ # this ensures all data points are incorportated
    
    a <- length(x) - max(csizes)
    
    sizes[length(sizes)] <- tail(sizes, 1) + a
    
  }
  
  if(length(csizes) - length(sizes) >= 1){
    
    a <- length(csizes) - length(sizes)
    
    csizes <- head(csizes, -1)
    
  }
  
  # Now as we'll be performing a secant converging method, we'll need to create two
  # internal functions:
  
  # 1) Regularised K-Fold least squares
  # 2) Secant method
  
  
  REG_lsq <- function(x, y, folds, n, K, L){
    
    # x = x data from above
    # y = y data from above
    # folds was calculated by the umbrella function
    # K was decided when calling the umbrella function
    # L = Lambda
    
    cols <- n + 1 # One more column than the order of the formula to account for the constant.
    
    WW <- matrix(0, nrow = cols, ncol = folds)   # Store model coefficients in an array of length 'folds'.
    Loss <- 0
    for(i in seq(folds)){ # number of loops = number of folds
      
      if(i == 1){
        
        # Split the data into folds:

        fold_x <- x[seq(csizes[i], csizes[i] + sizes[i])]
        fold_y <- y[seq(csizes[i], csizes[i] + sizes[i])]
        
        train_y <- y[-seq(csizes[i], csizes[i] + sizes[i])]
        train_x <- x[-seq(csizes[i], csizes[i] + sizes[i])]
        
        for(a in seq(cols)){ # Create matrices for x depending on the order of the formula:
          
          if(a == 1){
            
            fold_X <- matrix(fold_x^(a-1), ncol = 1)
            train_X <- matrix(train_x^(a-1), ncol = 1)
            
          }else{
            
            fold_X <- cbind(fold_X, fold_x^(a-1))
            train_X <- cbind(train_X, train_x^(a-1))
            
          }
          
        }
        
        WW[, i] <- solve(t(train_X) %*% train_X + K * L * diag(length(train_X[1, ])), tol = NULL) %*% t(train_X) %*% train_y
        
        Fold_prediction <- fold_X%*%WW[, i]
        Loss[i] <- mean((Fold_prediction - fold_y)^2) + (L * t(WW[, i]) %*% WW[, i])
        
      }else{

        # Split the data into folds:
        
        fold_x <- x[seq(csizes[i] + 1, csizes[i] + sizes[i])]
        fold_y <- y[seq(csizes[i] + 1, csizes[i] + sizes[i])]
        
        train_y <- y[-seq(csizes[i] + 1, csizes[i] + sizes[i])]
        train_x <- x[-seq(csizes[i] + 1, csizes[i] + sizes[i])]
        
        for(a in seq(cols)){ # Create matrices for x depending on the order of the formula:
          
          if(a == 1){
            
            fold_X <- matrix(fold_x^(a-1), ncol = 1)
            train_X <- matrix(train_x^(a-1), ncol = 1)
            
          }else{
            
            fold_X <- cbind(fold_X, fold_x^(a-1))
            train_X <- cbind(train_X, train_x^(a-1))
            
          }
          
        }
        
        WW[, i] <- solve(t(train_X) %*% train_X + K * L * diag(length(train_X[1, ])), tol = NULL) %*% t(train_X) %*% train_y
        
        Fold_prediction <- fold_X%*%WW[, i]
        Loss[i] <- mean((Fold_prediction - fold_y)^2) + (L * t(WW[, i]) %*% WW[, i])
      }
      
    }
    
    assign("w", rowMeans(WW), envir = globalenv())
    Loss <- mean(Loss)
    return(Loss)
    
  }
  
  root_sec <- function(L1, L2, fun){
    
    Number_Of_Iterations = 0 # Starts the counter
    
    x1 = L1
    x2 = L2
    
    while(abs(x2 - x1) > 0.0001){
      
      Number_Of_Iterations <- Number_Of_Iterations + 1
      x_new = x2 - 
        (fun(x, y, folds, n, K, x2)*(x2 - x1)) / 
        (fun(x, y, folds, n, K, x2) - fun(x, y, folds, n, K, x1))
      
      
      if(abs(x2 - x_new) > abs(x_new - x1)){
        
        x2 = x_new
        
      }else{
        
        x1 = x_new
        
      }
      
    }
    
    return(cbind(L = x_new, Iterations = Number_Of_Iterations))
    
  }  
  
  L1 <- 0
  L2 <- 1
  
  L <- root_sec(L1, L2, REG_lsq)
  
  return(L)
  
}
```

When I run this with K = 5, for order of model = 1, I get Lambda = -6.152844e-05.

And for K = 5, order of model = 4, I get Lambda = -1.439062e+15

Now I really do not know if this is correct, and if this is how you're supposed to calculate the best value of Lambda. I find many of the explanations in the book a bit too brief, and I struggle to apply the concepts covered in the book.

Can the regularisation parameter, Lambda be negative, and are these values (x10^-5 and x10^15) too small and large, respectively?

Am I overcomplicating the process, or have I misunderstood the technique?

The data is as follows:

```
x <- c(1896, 1900, 1904, 1906, 1908, 1912, 1920, 1924, 1928, 1932, 1936, 1948, 1952, 1956,
       1960, 1964, 1968, 1972, 1976, 1980, 1984, 1988, 1992, 1996, 2000, 2004, 2008)

y <- c(12, 11, 11, 11.2, 10.8, 10.8, 10.8, 10.6, 10.8, 10.3, 10.3, 10.3, 10.4, 10.5, 10.2,
       10, 9.95, 10.14, 10.06, 10.25, 9.99, 9.92, 9.96, 9.84, 9.87, 9.85, 9.69)
```